# approximation simple functions with finite support

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be a nonnegative measurable function.  I want to prove that there is an increasing sequence of nonnegative simple functions each of which vanishes outside a set of finite measure such that $f=\lim_n \phi_n$.  Can someone give me a push in the right direction?  I can prove this in the case that the measurable domain is $\mathbb{R}$, but otherwise this is intractable to me.

Comment: Is this only true when the measurable domain $\mathbb{R}$?